# Find files with certain extensions

Tags: find, regular-expression

How can I use `find` to find all files that have a `.xls` or `.csv` extension? I have seen a `-regex` option but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Why not simply use this:

```
find -name "*.xls" -o -name "*.csv"
```

You don't need regex for this.

If you absolutely want to use regex simply use

```
find -regex ".*\.\(xls\|csv\)"
```

Comment: Better answer than mine.  +1.

Comment: Why is a backslash needed before the parenthesis?  I know it doesn't work without it, but it seems like it should.

Comment: @MCS - without them, it would match a literal ( or ) in the file name.

Comment: because they are emacs regular expressions by default. use -regextype to change that.

Comment: Just for the record: I can never remeber which tools want "\\(" for grouping and which want "(". I always have to try it to know it.

Comment: @saua - I'm glad I'm not the only one!

Comment: If the file names have any special characters (whitespace, newlines, etc) the default -print may cause problems with shell expansion.  To be absolutely safe you should use -print0 and xargs -0.

Comment: regex example does not work

Comment: By the way, the find on OSX doesn't support the "|" operator in regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905493/why-isnt-this-regex-working-find-regex-m-h

Answer (score 14):

```
find . \( -name  \*.xls -o -name \*.csv \) -print
```

Comment: Didn't know about the -o option.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it need parentheses? find . '(' -name \*.xls -o -name \*.csv ')'-print

Comment: @Adrian - no, it doesn't.  I'm not sure if it would need parens on a non-GNU find where "-print" wasn't already the default action.

Comment: Well, GNU find ( default on ubuntu 11.04) works correctly with both parens and -print OR without (parens and -print). But `find . -name \*.xls -o -name \*.csv -print` outputs only files matching .csv,

Comment: You're right, I need the parens.

Comment: +1 for grouping them; very useful if you want to use some more options.